# String.Format throws 'Input string was not in a correct format' for Arabic Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, localization, arabic

I have been getting common error **'Input string was not in a correct format'** while trying to replace parameters from string which contains Arabic text. Though it's not happening for every Arabic text.

Example:

```
‪{تم ايداع الالية لرقم السجل {0
```

Following code fails for above text.

```
string str= "{تم ايداع الالية لرقم السجل {0";
object[] subjectText = new object[] { "10112" };
str = string.Format(str, subjectText);
```

I understand that there has to be a way we could sanitize or format string in such way that string format doesn't throw exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the `char[]`; that string is actually:

```
{
```

then a whole bunch of arabic including ltr/rtl, then

```
} 0
```

For it to work as a replacement, the characters `{0}` must be adjacent and in the correct order.

This works fine:

```
string str = "{0} تم ايداع الالية لرقم السجل";
```

(it looks the same, but is very different construction; also, you must decide whether the `{0}` is meant to be at the start ltr vs the end rtl).

Comment: Funny, this works too `string str = "تم ايداع الالية لرقم السجل{0}";` :)

Comment: @L.B that one surprises me due to the lack of a visible `{`, but: confirmed; the reversal is in the rendering - it really does contain `{0}` (at the character level)

Comment: @L.B : How do you convert such text? Or you just moved first character to the end of string?

Comment: @MarcGravell: So there is no programmatic solution for such problem? Do i have to format every Arabic string like this?

Comment: @Sangram maybe you can use this: `var str1 = "تم ايداع الالية لرقم السجل";  var str = str1 + "{0}";`

Comment: @Sangram I don't understand the question; if the question is "do I need to format every Arabic string such that the `{0}` are adjacent": then: if you want it to work with `string.Format`, then: **yes**. It doesn't need to be specifically at the start or end, but the characters **must** be next to each-other. Think about what `string.Format` is doing: it is basically "find the index of `{`, find the following index of `}`, parse the integer between them, replace the substring between-and-including those tokens with the parameter at the parsed ordinal".

Comment: @L.B: I was actually picking up the string from DB. :(. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @MarcGravell: okay. So that is how it has to work. Your workaround is pretty explanatory. Thanks a bunch